Painting over stained and polyurethaned wood trim
I have some trim boards that I had previously stained and poly’d (water based). I’m not too crazy about how it turned out and want to paint them instead. I have some Sherwin Williams Emerald Urethane trim enamel that I’d like to use to paint over.
My question is: what surface prep do I need to do before painting?

I have had this same circumstance. Stained and poly trim I wanted to reuse as painted.
Water based poly is not as hard as oil based. I cleaned the pieces and scuffed then with a general purpose scuffing pad. Cleaned off the dust and painted them with a water base semi-gloss. Didn't need primer as the scuffing gave the paint something to stick to.
The pieces have been in my house for over 9 years and survived normal use and cleaning and still look great. Not a single inch got pealed or bubbled paint. No stain blead through.

You'll probably have to scuff-sand the polyurethane surface to remove the glossiness that may be there. Glossy surfaces don't hold surface coatings well. Then prime with a primer compatible with the poly and the new paint, then paint.
"Compatible" can be determined by asking a local paint store what primer to use, based on what manufacturer of polyurethane is on the pieces now and what paint you want to put on them.

A water-based paint should work over water-based polyurethane. But it might be a good idea to apply a universal (shellac and alcohol based) primer first, to help guarantee adhesion.
